# Finding if there's a similar decimal digit in two ints

Tags: java

I currently take a Java class in my high school, and I need to find a code to help me find if there's a similar number in two ints.

For example, in the ints 49 and 93, there's one similar digit in both ints (which is 9.)
I need to write a code to see if there's a mutual digit.

UPDATE: You guys were asking what I've tried, which I have already commented about down below, here it is.

```
//Declaring
int a= 12;
int b= 23;
char a1= a.charAt(0); //An obvious coding error
```

UPDATE: This is what I tried, thanks to Mohammad Adil's suggestion.

```
    int a= 12;
    int b= 23;
    String firstInt = "";
    String secondInt = "";
    firstInt= Integer.toString(a);
    secondInt= Integer.toString(b);
    int firstCharA= firstInt.charAt(0);
    int secondCharA= firstInt.charAt(1);
    int firstCharB= secondInt.charAt(0);
    int secondCharB= secondInt.charAt(1);
```

UPDATE: Here are the comparisons.

```
if(firstCharA == firstCharB || firstCharA == secondCharB || secondCharA == firstCharB || secondCharA == secondCharB)
        {
            output = true;
        }
        else
        {
            output = false;
        }

        System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: convert them to string, read every character of first string and see if the other string contains that char. or not .

Comment: Do you mean common digits? If, say, the numbers are 1491 and 14391, what output are you coding for?

Comment: @ZouZou, I thought of using char, and comparing all 4 digits one-by-one. But that obviously wouldn't have worked.

Comment: @MohammadAdil, mask both ints to String, finding each "char"s, and comparing them?

Comment: @user3320549 Show us what you've tried.

Comment: @ChthonicProject, output has to be a Boolean. True if there's a common digit, false if there isn't any.

Comment: @user3320549 you keep writing about what you need but never say **what have you tried to solve this** and **where you're stuck**.

Comment: First convert each number to a decimal string.  Next convert each string to an array of char.  Next write a double loop to loop through one array and compare to each char of the other array.  When you find a match you can `break` the loop, but be sure to set a `boolean` value first to remember that you found the match.

Comment: (Anything beyond that is more info than you should be given -- you don't learn if you don't try.)

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: No more planning, start doing.

Comment: I have corrected your text so as to remove the confusion. What you are looking for are decimal digits (that is, characters).

Comment: //declaring int a= 12;
        int b= 23;
        char a1= a.charAt(0); //this gave me an error

Comment: When we say *show what have you tried* we mean *post your current code and show us where are you stuck*. You're a programmer/developer/software engineer or related and this site is for programmers/developers/software engineers, so you have to talk in our terms, not as a non-programmer.

Comment: @user3320549 Did you not correct the error?

Comment: So you have a hypothesis but you have not actually tried it. What you should do is try it. Your hypothesis is certainly one way to achieve this. You'll use two for loops. We don't want to just write this for you because you won't learn how to solve problems.

Comment: @user3320549 The second comment gives you a solution to achieve what you want. Why don't you try to implement it?

Comment: In Java, `int`s **are not** `String`s, so they don't have `charAt` method. In fact, `int`s do not have any method since they're primitive types, not classes.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, how about now?

Comment: @HotLicks, how about now?

Comment: @Ingo, how about now?

Comment: @ZouZou, how about now?

Comment: @user3320549 **NEVER** delete content of your previous answer, instead add the new content and say the old is deprecated, in order to follow the history of the question.

Comment: @user3320549 I don't see any comparisons here...

Comment: @ZouZou, I was just working on it, and posted it. :)

Comment: The your current solution only works with number with two digits. You need to make it more dynamic.

Comment: @Elias, yes. But only 2 digits are going to be used. :)

Comment: Instead of using characters, you can extract digits using mod and divide.  Ones digit = number % 10.  Tens digit = (number / 10) % 10.

Answer (score 3):

In a simple way:

```
int a is 12
int b is 23
bool contains is false
for each char in b
    verify if a contains current b char
        then
            contains become true
            break the loop
        otherwise
            go to next b char
print contains
```

Comment: thanks! Since I haven't learned it yet, it looks weird. But I kind of get what's what.

Comment: It's just the algorithm.You need to translate it to the Java language.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written only works for two digit integers.
A more general case would be

```
public class DuplicateDigits {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        DuplicateDigits d = new DuplicateDigits();
        Random random = new Random();
        int maxRandom = 10000;
        for (int iTest = 0; iTest < 100; iTest++) {
            int a = random.nextInt(maxRandom) + 1;
            int b = random.nextInt(maxRandom) + 1;
            boolean output = d.hasSameDigits(a, b);
            if (output) {
                System.out.println(a + " and " + b + " have duplicate digits");
            } else {
                System.out.println(a + " and " + b + " do not have duplicate digits");
            }
        }

    }

    public boolean hasSameDigits(final int a, final int b) {
        int digitsA[] = extractDigits(a);
        int digitsB[] = extractDigits(b);
        for (int digitA : digitsA) {
            for (int digitB : digitsB) {
                if (digitA == digitB) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private int[] extractDigits(int number) {

        LinkedList<Integer> stack = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        while (number > 0) {
            stack.push(number % 10);
            number = number / 10;
        }
        int digits[] = new int[stack.size()];
        for (int index = 0; index < stack.size(); index++) {
            digits[index] = stack.get(index);
        }
        return digits;
    }

}
```